# How can I transfer a camera animation to a single bone in an armature?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, camera

I have a camera with an animation that came from tracking a video (this animation only consists of rotations). 
I need to transfer its keyframes to a specific bone(placed in the same position of the camera) of a rig, so that it will have a animation that mimics the camera's movement. 
I managed to use a copy of the camera action with the armature, but this makes the whole armature rotate with the camera. I guess this happens because it is applying the animation to the armature's object, and not specific bones.

**How can I make a single bone of the armature use a copy of the camera's animation?**

Thank you.

Comment: With a copy transforms constraint on the bone.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm trying to get a editable animation with keyframes for the bone. Adding the constraint does not create a new action for the bone.

Comment: Add the constraint, select the bone. Press space and search for *bake*, then choosen NLA bake. In the bake dialog, choose visual transform and remove constraints. The visual transformed animation has now been baked to keyframes.